# Knockout.js & list of checkboxes: post to mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have an MVC view model that looks like this:

```
public class DirectorySearchModel
{
    [Display(Name = "First name contains")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last name contains")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public CountriesCollection Countries { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Country> SelectedCountries { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Country> AllCountries { get; set; }
}
```

The CountriesCollection object (line 9) looks like this:

```
public class CountriesCollection
{
    [Display(Name = "Countries")]
    public int[] arrCountries { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I'm creating a new, blank instance of CountriesCollection and then adding it to a blank instance of the DirectorySearchModel view model and then serialising it all into a javascript view model for Knockout.js:

```
{
"FirstName":null,

"LastName":null,

"Countries":{"arrCountries":[]},

"SelectedCountries":[{"RelationshipManager":{},"CountryId":1,"CountryName":"UK"},{"RelationshipManager":{},"CountryId":2,"CountryName":"France"},{"RelationshipManager":{},"CountryId":3,"CountryName":"Spain"}],

"AllCountries":[{"RelationshipManager":{},"CountryId":1,"CountryName":"UK"},{"RelationshipManager":{},"CountryId":2,"CountryName":"France"},{"RelationshipManager":{},"CountryId":3,"CountryName":"Spain"}]
}
```

My checkboxes are rendered as: `<input checked="checked" data-bind="checked: Countries.arrCountries" id="Countries_arrCountries30" name="Countries.arrCountries" type="checkbox" value="1">`. Checking a couple means you end up with this Knockout.js view model:

```
{
"FirstName":null,

"LastName":null,

"Countries":{"arrCountries":["1", "3"]},

"SelectedCountries":[{"RelationshipManager":{},"CountryId":1,"CountryName":"UK"},{"RelationshipManager":{},"CountryId":2,"CountryName":"France"},{"RelationshipManager":{},"CountryId":3,"CountryName":"Spain"}],

"AllCountries":[{"RelationshipManager":{},"CountryId":1,"CountryName":"UK"},{"RelationshipManager":{},"CountryId":2,"CountryName":"France"},{"RelationshipManager":{},"CountryId":3,"CountryName":"Spain"}]
}
```

Submitting my view normally (i.e. via a submit button and not with Knockout.js) to an MVC action that expects a `DirectorySearchModel`, I'm able to ask for `model.Countries.arrCountries` to get a list of the checked items, but when I use...

```
$.post("/MyController/MyAction", ko.toJS(viewModel), function(returnData) {
    $("#resultCount").html(returnData);
});
```

or...

```
$.post("/MyController/MyAction", viewModel, function(returnData) {
    $("#resultCount").html(returnData);
});
```

to another action that expects the same `DirectorySearchModel`,  `model.Countries.arrCountries` is always `null`! I wondered if it's due to Knockout.js posting the `arrCountries` entries as `string[]`s when MVC is expecting `int[]`s, but changing my MVC code to expect `string[]`s doesn't seem to change much..! The `CountriesCollection` object within the `DirectorySearchModel` appears to exist, but it's the `arrCountries` within that's always `null`.

Any ideas? Any help much appreciated!

### Edit

The action that receives the Knockout.js viewModel:

```
public MvcHtmlString ResultCount(DirectorySearchModel model)
{
    return new MvcHtmlString(getResultCount(model).ToString());
}
```

The `getResultCount` method:

```
public int getResultCount(DirectorySearchModel model)
{
    IUserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository();
    int count = userRepository.Search(model, null).Count();
    return count;
}
```

### FIXED!

Thanks to Konstantin for pointing out that a simple switch from $.post to $.ajax to send my Knockout.js view model back to my mvc action was all that was needed! Here's the $.ajax code I'm using:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",
    url: "/MyController/MyAction",
    data: ko.toJSON(viewModel),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#resultCount").html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you use Fiddler or a built-in browser debugging tool to see what is actually going across the network?

Comment: or even just a `console.log(ko.toJS(viewModel))` to confirm what is being posted

Comment: Thanks for the replies, guys! Paul's console.log suggestion reveals that upon checking a checkbox, you end up with: `Countries` (`Object`) containing `arrCountries` (`Array[1]`), which contains `0: "2"`, so it does look like the Knockout.js viewModel does contain the data... Just a case of getting my c# to accept it, it seems!

Comment: @user1390429 are you still looking for an answer for this? If so, can you show your controller method

Comment: Hi Paul, I am. Here's my controller:  `public MvcHtmlString ResultCount(DirectorySearchModel model)
        {
            return new MvcHtmlString(getResultCount(model).ToString());
        }`  which calls:  `public int getResultCount(DirectorySearchModel model)
        {
            IUserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository();
            int count = userRepository.Search(model, null).Count();

            return count;
        }`  userRepository.Search is a standard query = query.Where(...) deal that adds clauses depending on what info was entered/is in the model.

Comment: @user1390429 can you include it in the question, so it's formatted better?

Comment: @user1390429 can you also post the DirectorySearchModel class structure?

Comment: @paulslater19 Done! The DirectorySearchModel class is the first code block in my question. Really appreciate you taking a look at this for me!

Comment: @user1390429 hmmm... Could you pass the `Countries` object stringified? 
e.g. `var obj = ko.toJS(viewModel); obj.Countries = ko.toJSON(obj.Countries);` .... then .... `$.post("/url", ko.toJSON(obj), function(data) { /*...*/ });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use $.post you need to go for the underlying $.ajax and add the correct contenttype to make mvc accept the posted json and do the model binding (contenttype should be "application/json; charset=utf-8") google for it and you will se lots of examples

Comment: I know this applies to asp.net forms, but I don't think it does for MVC

Comment: Thanks Konstantin! This sorted it! Days of messing around and my original setup works perfectly simply by switching from $.post to $.ajax!

Comment: Thanks to paul and Holf for their help - very, very much appreciate all your work on this! Will update my question with the $.ajax code I'm using.